# Problem with response values with join in django query?

Tags: django

i have this models.

```
class Product(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
PublicationDate = models.DateField()
trend = models.IntegerField()

class User_list(models.Model):
product_id = ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
userid = models.IntegerField()
```

i make a join query with select related

```
data = User_list.objects.select_related('product_id')
```

but the response don't get me Product fields value.

it's get me only User_list values, like this

```
"[{\"model\": \"app.user_list\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"product_id\": 11916, \"userid\": 9}}]"
```

What's the problem?

Comment: I believe you should use .all() ; like  data = User_list.objects.select_related('product_id').all()

Comment: It doesn't work. Get me the same output.

Comment: Can you show how you output `User_list`?